# Implement same logic for diffrent objects as T

Tags: vb.net

I suppose to use T but i am not sure how do it in proper way.

Let's consider following example.

Base class:

```
Public Class HtmlBase
            Implements IGetInformation

   Public Overridable Function IsExist() As Boolean Implements IGetInformation.IsExist
           Throw New NotImplementedException()
   End Function

   Public Overridable Function GetIdByName(pName As String) As Integer Implements IGetInformation.GetIdByName
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
   End Function

End Class
```

Example classes which inherit from base class:

```
Public Class HtmlSubSection
      Inherits HtmlBase

'--sometimes i have to overload to add additioinal parameter
Public Overloads Function isExist(subsection As String) As Boolean
      Dim dlsubkategorie As New DataLayer.DALSubSection
      Return dlsubkategorie.CheckIfSubSectionExist(subsection)
End Function

Public Overrides Function GetIdByName(subsectionName As String) As Integer
      Dim dlget As New DataLayer.DALSubSection
      Return dlget.GetSubSectionIdByName(subsectionName)
End Function

End Class


Public Class HtmlSection
     Inherits HtmlBase

    'sometime i have to overload to add additioinal parameter

Public Overloads Function IsExist(section As String) As Boolean
     Dim dlsubkategorie As New DataLayer.DALSection
     Return dlsubkategorie.CheckIfSectionExist(section)
End Function

Public Overrides Function GetIdByName(Name As String) As Integer
      Dim dlsubkategorie As New DataLayer.DALSection
      Return dlsubkategorie.GetSectionIdByName(Name)
      End Function
End Class
```

As could be seen above two classes which inherits from base within their methods has same logic (sometimes i have to use additional parameter therefore overloads there, but are using diffrent DAL class to call. I would like to implement this logic in base class and for each just point to specific DAL. How to do that to not everytime in those classes write e.g:

```
Dim dlsubkategorie As New DataLayer.<DALSection>
Return dlsubkategorie.GetSectionIdByName(Name)
```

**EDIT:**

Htmlbase constructor's:

```
 Sub New()
    End Sub

    Sub New(pId As Integer)
        _Id = pId
    End Sub
```

HtmlSubSection's constructors:

```
 Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        AvailableSentences = New List(Of HtmlSubSection_Sentence)
        SelectedSentences = New List(Of HtmlSubSection_Sentence)
    End Sub
    Sub New(pId As Integer)
        MyBase.New(pId)
    End Sub
    Sub New(pName As String)
        _Name = pName
    End Sub

    Sub New(pId As Integer, pName As String)
        MyBase.New(pId)
        _Name = pName
    End Sub
```

HtmlSection's constructors:

```
Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Sub New(pId As Integer)
        MyBase.New(pId)
    End Sub
    Sub New(pId As Integer, pName As String, pPosition As Integer)
        MyBase.New(pId)
        _Name = pName
        _Position = pPosition
    End Sub

    Sub New(pName As String)
        _Name = pName
    End Sub

    Sub New(pName As String, pPosition As Integer)
        _Name = pName
        _Position = pPosition
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need generic types here. Just use Interfaces, Sub Classing and Polymorphism correctly.

New Interface IDAL which is implemented by DAL classes to get rid of different method names which take same parameters and do the same:

```
Public  Interface  IDAL
        Function  CheckIfSectionExist(section As string) As Boolean
        Function  GetSectionIdByName(section As string) As Integer
End Interface

 Public  Class DALSection
        Implements  IDAL

        Public Function  CheckIfSectionExist(section As string) As Boolean Implements IDAL.CheckIfSectionExist
            ...
        End Function

        Public Function GetSectionIdByName(section As String) As Integer Implements IDAL.GetSectionIdByName
            ...
        End Function
 End Class

    Public  Class DALSubSection
        Implements  IDAL

       Public Function  CheckIfSubSectionExist(subSection As string) As Boolean Implements IDAL.CheckIfSectionExist
            ...
        End Function

        Public Function GetSubSectionIdByName(subSection As String) As Integer Implements IDAL.GetSectionIdByName
            ...
        End Function
    End Class
```

Base class changed to abstract and the constructor now takes IDAL parameter. Function can now be executed polymorphic. Added a `isExists(string)` function to avoid overloading:

```
Public MustInherit Class HtmlBase
            Implements IGetInformation

    Public Property DAL as DataLayer.IDAL
    Protected  Sub New(dal as DataLayer.IDAL)
        Me.DAL = dal
    End Sub

   Public Overridable Function isExist() As Boolean Implements  IGetInformation.isExist
         Return True 
   End Function 

   Public Overridable Function isExist(section As String) As Boolean
         Return DAL.CheckIfSectionExist(Section)
   End Function 

   Public Overridable Function GetIdByName(pName As String) As Integer Implements IGetInformation.GetIdByName
        Return DAL.GetSectionIdByName(pName)
   End Function
End Class
```

Client classes only need to give correct DAL to base class:

```
Public Class HtmlSubSection
      Inherits HtmlBase
    Public Sub New() 
        MyBase.New(New DataLayer.DALSubSection)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class HtmlSection
     Inherits HtmlBase

    Public Sub New() 
        MyBase.New(New DataLayer.DALSection)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Basically it would be ideal if `IGetInformation` had a `isExist` method with an optional string parameter. This would save one unneccessary method in `HtmlBase`.

Comment: What in case i have more constructors for each e.g HtmlSection, HtmlSubSection? Look at main EDIT i did  i show you how it exactly look currently. Do i have to always put this dal parameter inside all constructors or? Would appreciate your post modification according to that.